# how to move a json object inside another json to last position

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having a json like follows

```
var obj = {
    "key1" : ["value1"],
    "key2" : ["value2"],
    "key3" : ["value3"],
    "key4" : ["value4"]
}
```

What i need is if any thing updated or changed in values the corresponding object should move to last position. For eg., If value2 is changed to new value2 then i need to move "key2" and the new value to last position. (i.e) as follows

```
var obj = {
    "key1" : ["value1"],
    "key3" : ["value3"],
    "key4" : ["value4"],
    "key2" : ["new value2"]
}
```

how to do this in json?

Comment: you don't deal with json directly. it's just a string. You decode the JSON into a native data structure, manipulate that structure however you want, then convert it BACK to a json string. Plus, the ordering of keys in a structure is not relevant to JSON. you might get alphabetical, you might get internal storage order, whatever. there's no guarantee HOW the string will be produced.

Comment: they're just objects, btw. not json. objects don't have a sort order, therefore there is no way of doing what you want without turning your object into an array instead.

Comment: Why do you want to move it to last position? What ever the position, they represent a property.

Comment: Well, i guess technically you could keep a separate array that stored the order of the object keys... but that's a bit much when switching to an array isn't very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Objects/JSONs have no guaranteed order. Replace your wrapper with an Array.

Comment: You mean object, not JSON.

Comment: Because a JSON string can also represent an array, which DOES have a guaranteed order.

Comment: I wouldn't bet my money on it. According to [JSON.org](http://json.org/) they do, but in my experience they are handled inconsistently across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your wrapper object of type array.

Comment: That's invalid syntax.  Arrays don't have keys like that.